# How can I test "Rate my App" functionality?

Tags: android, unit-testing, google-play, android-2.1-eclair

I've got a bit of code in my app, that after X number of days will check if the user has rated the app, and if not, prompt them to do so.

How can I feasibly JUnit test this in a painless manner? The emulator doesn't have the market application by default, but there are plenty of tutorials to set that up.

Is there a way to stub this out so a unit test can check if the app has been rated, and if not attempt to rate it?

I'm a little bit stuck on ideas on how I can actually verify this bit of code works, without running it manually

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a similar issue myself and so I simply wrote a quick app that would handle a market Uri activity.

Subsequently however, I came across this:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/21862/how-to-enable-the-android-market-in-the-google-android-emulator/

I've not tried it yet myself, but if it allows you to set up the market app on your emulator, this would likely be the ideal solution.